# TYPO3: Set PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR in TCA for foreign_table_where

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

With the folloging TCA configuration I am trying to set the PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR marker for `foreign_table_where`

TCA field configuration:

```
'my_field' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
    'label' => 'The label',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_my_foreign_table',
        'foreign_table_where' => ' ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### AND tx_my_foreign_table.deleted = 0 AND tx_my_foreign_table.hidden = 0 AND tx_my_foreign_table.sys_language_uid = ###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid### ORDER BY tx_my_foreign_table.lastname ASC, tx_my_foreign_table.firstname ASC',
        'MM' => 'tx_my_table_mm',
        'size' => 10,
        'autoSizeMax' => 30,
        'maxitems' => 99,
    ],
],
```

As soon as I set the following Page TSConfig, I don't get any foreign records anymore:

```
TCEFORM.tx_table.my_field.PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR = AND tx_my_foreign_table.pid = 1
```

This was working perfectly in TYPO3 7, but stoped working in TYPO3 8. Do I need to change anything for TYPO3 8?

**EDIT**

I did some more debugging and tracked this issue down to the class `TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormDataProvider\AbstractItemProvider` on line 1139. Here you will find the following code:

```
$pageTsConfigString = $connection->quote($pageTsConfigString);
```

This results in `'AND tx_my_foreign_table.pid = 1'` (with quotes!) which will generate this foreignTableClause - and this is of course wrong because of the quotes:

```
'AND tx_mdnewsauthor_domain_model_newsauthor.pid = 1' AND tx_my_foreign_table.deleted = 0 AND tx_my_foreign_table.hidden = 0 AND tx_my_foreign_table.sys_language_uid = 0 ORDER BY tx_my_foreign_table.lastname ASC, tx_my_foreign_table.firstname ASC
```

Now my new questions: Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your Problem ist that '###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR###' set a value for this marker in the TSconfig pages. This value is checked using $ GLOBALS ['TYPO3_DB'] -> quoteStr () and backs up your SQL command. That "$ GLOBALS ['TYPO3_DB'] -> quoteStr ()" is your problem now.

Comment: @episch Thanks four your comment! Thats exactly what I found out in the last few minutes ;-) Strange part is, that it was working in TYPO3 7, so the quoting was done with `$pageTsConfigString = $connection->quote($pageTsConfigString);` and in TYPO3 8 it is done by `$pageTsConfigString = $connection->quote($pageTsConfigString);` So which behaviour is intended to be right? Should it never have been worked?

Comment: you cant write ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### in a quote. You have to concat or something like that to prepare your TypoScript Where SQL Statement.

Comment: @episch Can you point me in the right direction? How could I concat the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the SQL code in the TsConfig, put it into the TCA.

```
'foreign_table_where' => ' AND ( ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### = \'FALSE\' OR tx_my_foreign_table.pid = ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### ) AND tx_my_foreign_table.deleted = 0 AND tx_my_foreign_table.hidden = 0 AND tx_my_foreign_table.sys_language_uid = ###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid### ORDER BY tx_my_foreign_table.lastname ASC, tx_my_foreign_table.firstname ASC',
```

And

```
TCEFORM.tx_table.my_field.PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR = FALSE
```

Comment: Hm, the goal having the SQL string in the TsConfig was, that the pid was optional. With this TCA config it is mandatory. Are there other ways to have it optional again?

Comment: I don't know, if multiple ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### are allowed, but you could try `AND ( ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### IS NULL OR  ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### = '' or tx_my_foreign_table.pid =  ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### ) AND ....`

Comment: you are my personal hero, this is working!!! In TsConfig I use `TCEFORM.tx_table.my_field.PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR = FALSE` as default and my TCA looks like this `AND ( ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### = \'FALSE\' OR tx_my_foreign_table.pid = ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR### ) AND ....` If you edit your answer accordingly, I will accept it. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: @chris I did edit my answers according to your comment